# Why the timezone vary from main method and form web application in java

Tags: java, time, timezone

I am getting the system current timezone:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone systemTimeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

1. If I run from the Java main method, it gives the correct system timezone.
2. If I run from the web application (from REST web services) it gives `Asia/Irkutsk` as a         timezone.

But it is wrong, why?

Comment: 'system current timezone' - where do you run this main method? Where do you run the web application?

Comment: What web server are you using?  For instance, if it was JBoss, the timezone is specified at startup, which could be wrong.

Comment: i am using appache tomcat

Comment: Which time zone did you want instead?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Use *java.time* classes.
- Specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.

Example:

```
ZonedDateTime                     // Represents a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.
.now(                             // Capture the current moment as seen in this time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )   // Real time zone names are in `Continent/Region` format. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `IST`, `EST`, or `CST`. 
)
```

Generally best to use UTC for most of your work.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Details

The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) keeps a default time zone. This default is implicitly applied unless you specify one.

When you run your Java app locally, the current default time zone of your local JVM is implicitly applied.

When you run a Java web app, the current default time zone of the Servlet container's JVM is implicitly applied.

I suggest you stop using the terrible date-time classes such as `Calendar`. These are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

I strongly suggest always specifying your desired/expected time zone. The default zone is outside your control as a programmer. Either the sysadmin or any other code in any app within the JVM can change the default time zone while your app is running.

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

To capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).